# Does Android perform boolean short-circuiting?

Tags: java, android, short-circuiting

I know that Java performs optimization for double ampersands in boolean expressions, such as

```
if(a && b)
```

If `a` is false, b is not evaluated. Does this apply to the Android platform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a Java language rule and is converted by the compiler into appropriate Java bytecode. The Dalvik toolset then converts the bytecode into `.dex` files. Therefore, the Java system will apply the short-circuiting appropriately before the Android system even processes the code.

Comment: All the stuff about how the code is compiled to bytecodes and translated to dex, etcetera is an *implementation detail* and *irrelevant*.  The correct answer is this is the Java language, and Java's short-circuiting semantics are *specified* by the JLS.  The JLS does not permit platform specific behaviour for this kind of thing.

Comment: @StephenC Thus the opening phrase, which really isn't ambiguous or unclear in the slightest.

Comment: @chryslis - I said **irrelevant** ... not ambiguous or unclear.  If you realize everything but the open phrase is irrelevant ... why did you write them?  :-)

Comment: @StephenC Because I find understanding how the Android build process works to be helpful in reasoning about what aspects are identical (syntax) and what parts may differ in unexpected ways (parts of the runtime).

Comment: @chryslis - Unfortunately, your reasoning is flawed.  It is giving you the right answer, but for the wrong reasons.  To illustrate, if Android Java was not constrained by the JLS, then the Dalvik toolset could (theoretically / hypothetically) detect that the Java bytecodes that implement the short-circuiting `&&` and translate them into Dalvik bytecodes that for a non-short-circuiting `&`.  By your reasoning, how do you know that this doesn't happen ... and that Android Java isn't different?

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't have any choice. It is required to do so by the [Java Language Specification #15.23](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.23).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Android uses Java for its platform. It is a language rule in Java, and so it is in Android